# Compatibility problem with Chrome 85?

Tags: bug, edits, google-chrome

I upgraded to Chrome 85 (on MacOS High Sierra) last night. Today I'm noticing a number of strange display issues related to editing, I suspect they may be related.

When I'm editing a question or answer, I no longer see the live preview.

When I'm viewing a question, and someone edits the question or an answer, the edited item completely disappears until I refresh the page.

Is this just happening to me, or are others seeing similar problems? I'll check to see if disabling extensions clear it up, but I wanted to get this on the record first.

I use the Style Code After Edit Refresh extension, the author mentions that they changed something that impacts this. I'll try disabling until he announces the fix.

UPDATE

After disabling and re-enabling extensions a few times, the problem seems to have gone away.

UPDATE 2

It's still happening intermittently.

Comment: Live preview works fine for me. Chrome 85.0.4183.83 on Win10

Comment: I tried disabling and re-enabling extensions a few times, and now the problem seems to have gone away.

Comment: Maybe just caching issue.

Comment: It may well be an issue with Style Code After Edit Refresh which IIRC you use(d) (and I noticed was occasionally causing issues for me as well). They very recently added `initializeSpoilers` as a property to the function itself which the userscript wasn't expecting, I'll fix it soon

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, I'll await an update.